# mysql group replication, how to relocate replication channel from one master to another

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-8.0

Here is the scenario:

Site A → Replication → Site B

On Site A, there is a source database running, denoted as SDB.

On Site B, there is a Group Replication cluster (GRC) consisting of three servers: M1 (master), S1 (slave), and S2 (slave).

The replication channel is defined on M1 (and on the rest of the servers in the group). However, when M1 goes down, a new master is chosen. My goal is to relocate the replication channel from the currently down M1 to the new master. I want to ensure that replication from SDB continues, irrespective of the current master of the GRC.

I can identify the new chosen master using ProxySQL, but the channel metadata is not replicated. There are tables under the mysql database that contain relevant information:

slave_master_info

slave_relay_log_info

slave_worker_info

Simple command on new master:  start replica for channel 'xxx';

Would start the replica as it was defined and not from the place where the replica was on "old" master.

The table mysql.slave_master_info is not replicated and not get updated on the replicas of group replication cluster (despite what mentioned in the documentation).

I've been considering creating a trigger on mysql.slave_master_info to capture and store the changes in an intermediate table that can be replicated. Then, when the old master goes down and the new master takes over, I would update mysql.slave_master_info with this data and initiate replication. However, before I delve into modifying MySQL in this way, I was hoping to find a better solution.

Any thoughts?

Thanks